# Round time records in xarray dataset

Tags: python-xarray

I have xarray dataset with time dimension "`'2017-08-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-08-18T00:00:00.000000000'`". I want to drop hours, minutes and seconds and retain `'2017-08-13'`, `'2017-08-18'`. What I tried so far is following.

```
ds['time'].dt.round('D')
ds['time'].dt.floor('D')
```

But they return the original date format.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please share your attemtps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding or flooring the times can change their values for the hours, minutes, seconds, etc., but their default string representation will still retain them, even if they are zero.  If you would like to print out just the year, month, and day of the dates, you may use the [`strftime` method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.dt.strftime.html) on the [`DatetimeAccessor`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html):

```py
ds.time.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: This script actually retained only 'yyyy-mm-dd', thank you so much @spencerkclark.